# use ios 9.2 keyboard down to hide

Tags: ios, objective-c, keyboard

When i use iOS simulators 8.2 , Hide keyboard right but use iPhone 6P (ios9.2)the keyboard down to hide like this [gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1Ie2.gif)

Answer (score 1):

Use `[self.view endEditing:YES]` in your `viewWillDissapear` to hide all textfield's keyboard when your view going to dismiss

Comment: then u might want to try manually hide the keyboard for that textfield eg.`[textField resignFirstResponder];`?

Comment: This effect is use [self.view endEditing:YES] in viewWillDissapear  http://i.stack.imgur.com/7fQwq.gif